# Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal element

Tags: apex

I am getting error "System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements" while executing below code. Getting error at "insert jobTitleTrans". How to fix that?

My code is:

```
// Fetching all the Job Library records into list
List < Job_Position_and_Title__c > jobLibrary = new List < Job_Position_and_Title__c > ();
jobLibrary = [select ID, Name, Job_Code__c, Level_0__c, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c, Level_4__c, Level_5__c,
 Job_Title_Override_Level_0_Long__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_1_Long__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_2_Long__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_3_Long__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_4_Long__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_5_Long__c,
 Job_Title_Override_Level_0__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_1__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_2__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_3__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_4__c, Job_Title_Override_Level_5__c,
 Accountabilities_Level_0__c, Accountabilities_Level_1__c, Accountabilities_Level_2__c, Accountabilities_Level_3__c, Accountabilities_Level_4__c, Accountabilities_Level_5__c,
 AKS_Level_0__c, AKS_Level_1__c, AKS_Level_2__c, AKS_Level_3__c, AKS_Level_4__c, AKS_Level_5__c,
 Education_Level_0__c, Education_Level_1__c, Education_Level_2__c, Education_Level_3__c, Education_Level_4__c, Education_Level_5__c,
 Experience_Level_0__c, Experience_Level_1__c, Experience_Level_2__c, Experience_Level_3__c, Experience_Level_4__c, Experience_Level_5__c,
 Impact_Level_0__c, Impact_Level_1__c, Impact_Level_2__c, Impact_Level_3__c, Impact_Level_4__c, Impact_Level_5__c,
 Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_0__c, Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_1__c, Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_2__c, Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_3__c, Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_4__c, Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_5__c,
 Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_0__c, Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_1__c, Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_2__c, Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_3__c, Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_4__c, Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_5__c,
 Supervision_Given_Received_Level_0__c, Supervision_Given_Received_Level_1__c, Supervision_Given_Received_Level_2__c, Supervision_Given_Received_Level_3__c, Supervision_Given_Received_Level_4__c, Supervision_Given_Received_Level_5__c
 from Job_Position_and_Title__c where Name = 'Enterprise Architect'
];


// Fetching all the Job Position Transactional records migrated from Job Library
List < Job_Position_Transactional__c > JobPosTran = new List < Job_Position_Transactional__c > ();
JobPosTran = [Select ID, Name, JobLibraryReferenceId__c from Job_Position_Transactional__c where JobLibraryReferenceId__c != null];
System.debug('Count of JobPosTran' + JobPosTran.Size());

// Job Position Transactional ID and JoblibraryReferenceID mapping
Map < id, id > JPTtoJTT = new Map < id, id > ();
for (Job_Position_Transactional__c JPTMap: [Select ID, Name, JobLibraryReferenceId__c from Job_Position_Transactional__c where JobLibraryReferenceId__c != null]) {
 JPTtoJTT.put(Id.valueOf(JPTMap.JobLibraryReferenceId__c), JPTMap.id);
}

List < Job_Title_Transactional__c > jobTitleTrans = new List < Job_Title_Transactional__c > ();

for (Job_Position_and_Title__c jobLib: jobLibrary) {

 ID JPTID;
 ID JobLibID;
 Job_Title_Transactional__c jTT = new Job_Title_Transactional__c();

 //Fetching the Job Position Transactional ID using JoblibraryReferenceID
 JobLibID = jobLib.id;
 if (JPTtoJTT.containsKey(JobLibID)) {
  JPTID = JPTtoJTT.get(JobLibID);
 }
 System.debug('JobPosTran ID' + JPTID);
 if (jobLib.Level_0__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '0';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_0_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_0__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
 if (jobLib.Level_1__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '1';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_1_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_1__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
 if (jobLib.Level_2__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '2';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_2_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_2__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
 if (jobLib.Level_3__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '3';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_3_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_3__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
 if (jobLib.Level_4__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '4';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_4_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_4__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
 if (jobLib.Level_5__c == true) {
  jTT.Name = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Level__c = '5';
  jTT.Job_Title__c = jobLib.Job_Title_Override_Level_5_Long__c;
  jTT.Job_Code__c = jobLib.Job_Code__c;
  jTT.Level_Sp_Resp__c = jobLib.Accountabilities_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Knowledge_Skill_and_Abilities__c = jobLib.AKS_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Education__c = jobLib.Education_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Minimum_Experience__c = jobLib.Experience_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Impact__c = jobLib.Impact_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Preferred_Education_or_Experience__c = jobLib.Preferred_Ed_and_or_Exp_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Problem_Solving__c = jobLib.Problem_Solving_Analysis_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Interaction__c = jobLib.Supervision_Given_Received_Level_5__c;
  jTT.Job_Position_Transactional__c = JPTID;

  jobTitleTrans.add(jTT);
 }
}
try {
 System.debug('Statement Before insert' + jobTitleTrans.Size());
 insert jobTitleTrans;
 System.debug('Statement after insert');
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: is that possible that Level_0__c, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c, Level_4__c or  Level_5__c are true in 2 or more cases?

Comment: cause if yes -- then you are adding few identical records into list and trying to insert them, what is failing. Change code to recreating jTT every time when you insert that to jobTitleTrans or avoid multiple adding of single record

Comment: Yes, it's possible. level_0__c to Level_5__c is possible in 2 or more cases.

Comment: Does that mean that corresponding jTT should be inserted more then once, or only once?

Comment: jobTitleTrans inserted only once. But one Job_Position_and_Title__c record may create one or more Job_Title_Transactional__c records based on levels.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say. You can not add the same sobject to list few times and insert it. You need to recreate that

Comment: So i can take each level as a different instances and insert all those. Like jobTitleTrans1, jobTitleTrans2. Am i right....